# How to throw exception from lambda expression using .orElseThrow in Java

Tags: java, lambda

I got a compilation failure

```
Compilation failure
[ERROR]  unreported exception java.lang.Throwable; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Why does this code not compile

```
Collections.singletonList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")
    .stream()
    .findAny()
    .orElseThrow(() -> {
        String msg = "Failed";
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
    }));
```

while this seems okay

```
Collections.singletonList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")
    .stream()
    .findAny()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Failed")));
```

is this related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8056983 or is the first code block wrong?

In VS Code and in Eclipse I do not get a syntax error from the IDE.

Comment: You need to do `return new IllegalArgumentException(msg)` in the first example, not `throw`. The `orElseThrow` function will do the throwing for you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Your first code snippet runs fine here (and doesn’t throw any exception). Tested on Oracle jdk-1.8.0_101 and jdk-11.0.3.

Comment: Both the above block of code compile fine for me. Is it an IDE specific issue, possibly? @marstran the `throw` within the block of code `{}` should compile as well.

Comment: @marstran your comment is misleading. Both lambdas are correct and `throw` is a valid statement in the first one. See my answer, please

Comment: @AndrewTobilko My comment is not misleading. I did not mention the compilation error at all. I simply pointed out that he should return the exception instead of throwing it himself inside `orElseThrow`. That's why I wrote a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two code snippets are different. In the first one, you *throw* an exception in the lambda. In the second one, you *return* an exception from the lambda.

To make the two snippets consistent, change the first one to

```
Collections.singletonList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")
    .stream()
    .findAny()
    .orElseThrow(() -> {
        String msg = "Failed";
        return new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
    }));
```

Comment: the `throw` should compile as well, its the `{}` block and not an expression. Apart from the type of `Supplier` provided, there is not much difference in what is inferred by `orElseThrow` there.